# Append/pop specific element of a string to the list when iterating over it

Tags: python, append, iteration

I want to know how to append and pop only specific element of a string

```
def letter(item):

    lst = []
    for i in item:
        if 'a' in item:
            # not sure what to put here
    return lst
```

Output:

```
lst = ['a']
```

I only want the function to append the letter `'a'` in `'apple'`, is that possible?

And is there a way to only remove a specific letter from a string using the `list.pop()` function?

Comment: Python code-smell #4: modifying the array while you are iterating over it.

Comment: What do you mean? Give `lst = ['a']` when `item` is `'apple'`?

Comment: Yeah, only return 'a' in the lst, so the lst will be lst=[a']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use list.pop(), you can first convert your string to a list:

```
def find_letter(item):
    lst = []
    item=list(item) #convert your string to list
    for index,letter in enumerate(item):
        if letter=='a':
            lst.append(letter) # add 'a' to your empty list
            item.pop(index) # remove 'a' from the original string
        item="".join(item) # convert back your list to a string
    return lst,item
```

This gives the following output:

```
>>> find_letter("apple")
>>> (['a'], 'pple')
```

Note that you can do much simpler using list comprehension:

```
def find_letter(item):
    word="".join([letter for letter in item if letter!='a'])
    lst=[letter for letter in item if letter=='a']
    return lst,word
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: You're welcome, please consider accepting the answer if this is what you needed ;)